# Snowflake - Dynamic Filter Condition inside CTE (Common Table Expression)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I am creating view in **Snowflake** that has CTE on base table without any filters. I have other CTEs that depend on Parent CTE to fetch further information.

Everything is working fine when I query all records from base table that has 45K rows. But when I query view for one particular ID, explain plan shows Base CTE is picking up 45K rows, joining rest of CTE on 45K rows then finally applying my unique ID filter and returning one row.

I am not getting any difference in performance pulling data for all records or one record. Snowflake is not optimizing base CTE to apply the filter criteria I am looking for.

Any suggestions how can I resolve this issue? I used local variables in filter criteria of base CTE but it is not viable solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_v AS 
WITH parent_cte as 
(select document_id, time, ...
   from audit_table
),

emp_cte as
(select employee_details, ...
   from employee_tab,
        parent_cte
   where parent_cte.document_id = employee_tab.document_id),

dep_cte as 
(select dep_details, ....
   from dependent_tab,
        emp_cte
  where ..........)
select * 
  from dep_cte, emp_cte, base_cte;
```

Now when I query the view for one document_id, plan is fetching all data and joining then applying filter which is not efficient.

select * from test_v where document_id = '1001';

I can't use these tables in one select with join condition as I am using "LATERAL FLATTEN" which is cross multiplying each base table record so I am going with CTE approach.

Appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Please supply some sample data and the result you want to achieve with that data. Further explanation would helpful: you say that you are using lateral flatten but that doesn’t appear in the SQL you’ve provided

Comment: Since your CTE's build on each other, why are you joining them all together in your final select?  You should just be able to select from your final CTE...in fact, that final CTE could be your final select, since it's returning everything (I assume).  You also make reference to a base_cte, but I don't see that code.  My suggestion is not to re-join the CTE's together in your final select, since you've already done that.

Comment: Have you considered using a [Materialized View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-materialized.html) (or several MVs) for that?

Comment: Thank you all. I am planning to use materialized view or create table and populate data using streams whichever works better.